# Write the function is_valid_date(month, day, year) that takes parameters for the month, day, and year

Tags: python, date

Write the function `is_valid_date(month, day, year)` that takes parameters for the month, day,
and year, and then returns True if this is a valid date and False if it is not a valid date. In this
function, you will call the helper functions, test the results (using if/else statements), print an
output message describing whether the date is valid or not, and then return True/False to complete
the function. 
How do I solve question 5? This is what I tried to do but it didn't work at all.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P2u3.jpg) is my definition and logistics.

Comment: Hi, please edit and insert your code here. Let us know what is failing and why errors you’re getting. Thanks

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) Note it doesn't suggest posting the code in a comment. Please [edit] your question and add the code to **it** instead.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you need to develop the habit of stepping through an instance of your code visually. Also I think you have your operators mixed up.

The mod operator % returns the remainder after division.
The // operator performs normal division and trashes the remainder, so 4//2 == 2, 5//3 == 1.

You can use % in if statements nicely because % returns 0 when it divides evenly. 0 evaluates to false.

if not a % b:
    print("a divides evenly into b.")

The // operator doesn't work well in if statements because it will not return 0 unless the result of the division is between 0 and 1, which means that a < b.

2 // 3 == 0 -> false
3 or more // 3 == 1 or more -> true

So you can just do a >= b instead for the same result.

This is definitely homework so please go through and try again with this knowledge, Google things you're not sure of, and internalize the concepts.